# How could I use react router and a routes object to navigate to a sub-route that can have 1 or more ids?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to solve a problem where I need to navigate to a potential subroute that has multiple IDs. Here's an example

`/about/{ids}/note/{noteId}/team`

that's more or less the example.

the `ids` data would either be one or more numbers. Wondering how I would do this using a
react router Hash router specifically. (Project limitations don't allow for data or browser router).

Answer (score 0):

React Router `useParams` doesn't permit anything but passing what's in the URL directly to the user.

To expand `ids` into multiple values, you can do this:

```js
const { ids: idsString } = useParams();
const ids = idsString.split(",");
```

Don't forget to wrap `ids` in a `useMemo` if you plan on passing it to a dependency array.